# How to include Docker environment arguments when running docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker / docker compose and am using it to deploy an API to a server. I found an [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi/) that I wish to use, which includes the option to add some environment variables, in particular:

> `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS`
>
> Any additional command line settings for Gunicorn can be passed in the
> `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` environment variable.
>
> Read more about it in the Gunicorn docs: Settings.
>
> These settings will have precedence over the other environment
> variables and any Gunicorn config file.
>
> For example, if you have a custom TLS/SSL certificate that you want to
> use, you could copy them to the Docker image or mount them in the
> container, and set `--keyfile` and `--certfile` to the location of the
> files, for example:
>
> `docker run -d -p 80:8080 -e GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--keyfile=/secrets/key.pem --certfile=/secrets/cert.pem" -e PORT=443 myimage`

I would like to add these two options (keyfile and certfile) as arguments to the docker run command, but instead pass `docker compose up` to create the images and run the container.

How would I go about doing that?

My **Docker** file is:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app
```

And my **docker-compose.yml** file is:

```
version: "3"

services:

  backend:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
```

I have tried adding a `CMD` line to the end of my Docker file but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `environment` key in you docker-compose.yml like this:

```
environment:
  GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS: --keyfile=/secrets/key.pem --certfile=...
  PORT: 443
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment